# Unmet dependencies and broken packages error while I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04, dependencies

`sudo apt upgrade` showing following error

```
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but 2.37-12 is installed
     libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) but 2.37-12 is installed
                 Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6)
     locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.37)
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`apt --fix-broken install` showing following error and the same error was shown in synaptic package manager when i tried to fix broken install

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but 2.37-12 is installed
     libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) but 2.37-12 is installed
                 Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6)
     locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.37)
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
    E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` command shows following error:

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libc-bin:
     libc-bin depends on libc6 (<< 2.36); however:
      Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.37-12.
    
    dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     libc-bin
```

`sudo apt-get install -f` shows following error

```
    Correcting dependencies... failed.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but 2.37-12 is installed
     libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) but 2.37-12 is installed
                 Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6)
     locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.37)
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
    E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

`sudo apt install libc6="2.35-0ubuntu3.6"` displayed following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.37) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is to be installed libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.37-12) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is to be installed libc6-dev : Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.37) E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried many things from the internet but everything shows one of these 2 or 3 errors. Please help me fix it. Please, please help! Thanks

`apt policy libc6` shows following output

```
    libc6:
      Installed: 2.37-12
      Candidate: 2.37-12
      Version table:
     *** 2.37-12 100
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         2.35-0ubuntu3.6 500
            500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
         2.35-0ubuntu3 500
            500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Is there any chance this could be fixed.I actually tried to install katoolin in my ubuntu 22.04 machine but everything went smooth till system upgrade and when it started upgrading,it showed the errors mentioned above. Please help me fix it?

OUTPUT OF  `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'`

```
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
    | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
    |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
    ||/ Name                                       Version                                 Architecture Description
    +++-==========================================-=======================================-============-================================================================================
    rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic               6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
    rc  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic               6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
    rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic             6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic             6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic       6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic       6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    rc  node-esprima                               4.0.1+ds+~4.0.3-2                       all          ECMAScript parsing infrastructure for multipurpose analysis
    rc  node-mime                                  3.0.0+dfsg+~cs3.96.1-1                  all          library for mime-type mapping for Node.js
    rc  node-source-map                            0.7.0++dfsg2+really.0.6.1-9             all          Mozilla source map generator and consumer - Node.js module
    rc  node-sprintf-js                            1.1.2+ds1+~1.1.2-1                      all          Node.js Pure JavaScript sprintf implementation
    rc  npm                                        8.5.1~ds-1                              all          package manager for Node.js
```

OUTPUT OF `uname -a`

```
    Linux ciph3r-Inspiron-3537 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Picking a package in your paste shows a 22.04 system should get `libc6 | 2.35-0ubuntu3.6  | jammy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which is not the `2.37-12` you have installed, thus you're either not using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, or have corrupted your install with packages intended for something else.  What are you using?  What do you get if you `apt policy libc6` as your provided details do **not** match a 22.04 system.

Comment: @guiverc   EVERY OUTPUT IS LISTED ABOVE.

Comment: "2.37-12" doesn't have "ubuntu" in the version so it's unofficial software. You either installed an untrusted .deb from the internet or added a bad third-party PPA. This is not supported. Your best option is to reinstall and stop installing unofficial software

Comment: reiinstall what?   OS or smething else

Comment: I meant backing up your files and reinstalling the OS. It is possible to fix this without a reinstall but it would involve a lot of work. If you want to bother with this, you can start by following rusty's comment

Comment: `sudo apt -f reinstall locales=2.35-0ubuntu3.6` I think there is started to go messed.  `locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.37)`
But as @DanielT mentioned this to repair will involve a lot of work. Save data and install anew.

Comment: @rusty   THE OUTPUT OF THE COMMANDS U ASKED ARE ABOVE?PLZ HAVE A LOOK.Synaptics already installed but fixing broken packages with that didn't work as well

Comment: @THORNHILL I've posted my answer, please check if it helps, and do give your feedback.

Comment: Does `synaptic` package manager's ***Custom Filters -> Broken*** even list any package or is it empty?

Comment: Can you give me the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep --invert-match '^ii'`  . I need to check if there are any held packages. Your error messages suggests to check so.

Comment: See my answer at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1450452/212123

Answer (score 0):

The output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` shows you can remove the following packages as done with `dpkg --remove ...` (these were listed `rc`). You need to purge them all. Lets remove them with:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic node-esprima node-mime node-source-map node-sprintf-js npm
```

Now, run these command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

I'm not sure if the problem will get fixed because the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep '^.[^i]'` didn't have much except some remains of old configuration files. Are there more in the output? However, you can give this a try. If it does not help you should backup your data and reinstall your system.